# Does Java Cipher and CipherOutputStream default to correct block size?

Tags: java, encryption

Using AES 256 CBC does CipherOutputStream default to using the correct block size for the algorithm when encrypting? (16 bytes / 128 bits)

Comment: As opposed to defaulting to using an incorrect block size?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. AES is only defined for a fixed block size of 128 bit and the default SunJCE provider implements exactly that ([OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/crypto/provider/AESConstants.java?av=f#40)).

You can check the block size by calling `Cipher#getBlockSize()`. There is no way to retrieve the block size from a `CipherOutputStream`, but you probably initialized it with a `Cipher` instance and can determine the block size from that.